# Linear Regressor - clip_gradients_by_norm- Invalid syntax

Tags: tensorflow, linear-regression, gradient-descent, clip

04 and python 3.6

I installed the application Tensor Flow and I don't understand an error detected by the system.
I wrote:

```
 my_optimizer=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.0000001)

 my_optimizer = tf.contrib.estimator.clip_gradients_by_norm(my_optimizer, 5.0)
```

The first line works perfectly but for the second one the system gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/hal9500/Bureau/essai1.py", line 43, in <module>
  my_optimizer= tf.contrib.estimator.clip_gradients_by_norm(my_optimizer,5.0)
   File "/home/hal9500/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/lazy_loader.py", line 53, in __getattr__
module = self._load()
File "/home/hal9500/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/lazy_loader.py", line 42, in _load
module = importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
File "/home/hal9500/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/home/hal9500/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib  /__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
from tensorflow.contrib import image
File "/home/hal9500/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/image/__init__.py", line 70, in <module>
from tensorflow.contrib.image.python.ops.single_image_random_dot_stereograms import single_image_random_dot_stereograms
 File "/home/hal9500/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/image/python/ops/single_image_random_dot_stereograms.py", line 27, in <module>
"_single_image_random_dot_stereograms.so"))
File "/home/hal9500/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/util/loader.py", line 56, in load_op_library
ret = load_library.load_op_library(path)
 File "/home/hal9500/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/load_library.py", line 73, in load_op_library
exec(wrappers, module.__dict__)
 File "<string>", line 27
def single_image_random_dot_stereograms(depth_values, hidden_surface_removal=True, convergence_dots_size=8, dots_per_inch=72, eye_separation=2,5, mu=0,333299994, normalize=True, normalize_max=-100, normalize_min=100, border_level=0, number_colors=256, output_image_shape=[1024, 768, 1], output_data_window=[1022, 757], name=None):
                                                                                                                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What can I do to solve this syntax error?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug that can occur with the Tensorflow Python API together with a locale other than en_US-UTF8. What seems to happen is that the wrong decimal point format is used when the Tensorflow Python API calls a function from the Tensorflow C++ backend.
See [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/21164) Github issue.

## Solution 1: Upgrade tensorflow

This bug should have been fixed with tensorflow v1.12. So upgrading tensorflow is for sure the most preferable solution.

## Solution 2: Set an English locale in Python

If you can't upgrade to a new keras version for some reason, then a quick workaround is to insert the following code **after** your other import statements:

```py
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, locale="en_US.UTF-8")
```

Many thanks to the user [hofingermarkus](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/21164#issuecomment-417274023) for sharing this workaround.

## Solution 3: Set an English locale in your OS

I had one situation where i couldn't upgrade keras due to compatibility issues and solution 2 did not work for some reason. In such a case, the easiest way is to change the locale of your operating system to English and to reboot the PC.